# Python problem with Request AttributeError: module 'request' has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, request

Ok, so I have an error and I don't know why. I want to request a bunch of links from a file

```
while True:
    code = file.readline().replace("\n", "")
    r = request.get(code)
    source = r.post(code)
    print(source.text)
    input()
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I ment from A file sorry guys.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you edit the full error (traceback) that could help us to help you.

Comment: do you mean `requests` module and do you have an `import requests` directive at the beginning of your script?

Comment: Also note that you can edit your own post if you find a typo or you want to add some more information to the question.

Comment: I have flagged this as off-topic as it was caused by the missing `requests` import.

Comment: @dspencer *Something* got imported, just not the module expected. Otherwise, you'd get a `NameError` regarding `request`.

Comment: The user has answered their own question indicating that this worked for them, so I'm not sure how that happened, but I don't think this question is helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

import requests at the beggining of the file